# How to force a drop-down to move down on IE 11?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have the following drop-down :

```
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option>Closed</option>
  <option>Open</option>
</select>
```

with the associated style:

```
select {
  font-family: Cursive;
  width:200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;  
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

My problem is that the drop-down is moving upward on IE 11: [image]

Where as on chrome it is working fine.
Any idea ?

Comment: What is background-image for?

Comment: The positioning of the expanded list for a select box is a browser implementation detail; it's not something you have any control of as a site designer. Some browsers typically display select boxes above the field if there is insufficient space below it. On mobile devices it's different again; they typically open the list in a full-screen popup. You can't do much about it; that's just how things are. I guess you could write your own javascript control to replace the selectbox, but that would surely be overkill just for this (and would likely have plenty of issues of its own)

Comment: background-image was by mistake,I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments, select menus are very browser specific and hard to style. Some even send the options into the twilight zone where they are seemingly not even a part of the window and any events will return null. It might not be worth trying to get this to look the same across browsers, also because of the mobile implementations, but I happened to be making something like this for no apparent reason. As it coincides with your question I might as well post it.

It's not the prettiest thing when it comes to HTML and CSS because it requires four additional elements - one wrapper (commonly used for styling select boxes with overflow hidden but I took a slightly different approach because I thought it looked better) and three absolutely placed elements. One is a styled button, another will hide the scrollbar that appears and the third is a minor hack.

Most important thing is that the user will not be able to click the select menu itself. When this happens, most is lost because after that it's limbo. For that the third element will be used. It will be put on top of the select box. Then when it's clicked, instead of directly opening the menu it will be faked by changing the size of the `select` element. The `div` covering the right side also serves another purpose. It's initially placed at the bottom and by getting it's offset we'll know the height of the box. This will be used to resize the button and set the correct size for the overlaying div.

Looks to be behaving quite predicatbly on all major Windows desktop browsers. For the mobile implications this script uses a touch support feature test and reverts to normal layout if that is the case. Could probably be tweaked (with a screen size check) to not exclude trackpad users.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvrbeW?editors=001)

Not too much relevant CSS. But important to style body background the same as the bar on the right. Transparency is used so the actual menu isn't visible before the image for the button loads.

```
$(function() {

var hub = $('#box'), list = $('select'),
impel = $('#open'), commit = $('#mark'), tract = $('#refer'),
zenith = tract.position().top,
extent = list.children().length, active;

if (touch()) {
impel.add(commit).add(tract).remove();
hub.fadeTo(0,1);
return;
}

impel.add(commit).height(zenith);
tract.addClass('bar');

hub.fadeTo(0,1).on('mouseup click', function(e) {

    e.stopPropagation();
});

commit.mouseup(function() {

    flip();
    show();
    active = true;
});

list.add(impel).click(function() {

    flip();
    active = !active;
    if (active) show();
    else hide();
});

$(window).click(function() {

    if (active) {
    flip();
    hide();
    active = false;
    }
});

function show() {list.attr('size', extent)}

function hide() {list.removeAttr('size')}

function flip() {commit.toggle()}

function touch() {

    return 'ontouchstart' in window
    || navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0
    || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0;
}
});
```